# HP PSC-2100 can't seem to get xsane and HPLIP (printing working)

Tags: hplip

I am trying to get my printer setup to both "Print" and "Scan", yep, I need to do both. Both attempts (yep, I've gone thru this twice).  The First time I was able to print just fine, but the scanner didn't work, xsane was complaining about hpaio, etc.

After I installed the ://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html  AllInONE software I was able to print and scan, then something went wrong  (THIS IS THE QUESTION ???)

ALL Print jobs immediately get put in "HELD" status, if I "RELEASE" them, they immediately go back to HELD.

Currently,  I am able to scan (perfectly might I add) without any problems, I installed the HPLIP from ://help.ubuntu.com/community/HpAllInOne  website after following some thread, it appeared that would solve my issues.

Working from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HpAllInOne, I am able to get a clean installed but when I get to the Synaptic steps, I appears to me that HPLIP is installed multiple times as the HP LIP Device manager report software version:3.12.2 Device Mgr: 15.0 (Qt4) while synaptic is reporting:3.11.7-1, which in the synaptic window appear NOT to be installed. In the synaptic window I only see "openprint-ppds" and "pxljr" as being installed.

Do I need to removed packages and start over , can I get back to "Out-of-the-box" easily ?

I'm guessing by installing the opensource version I shot myself, but I'm thinking that I wasn't able to scan or something, that why I ended up following the links to HPLIP support.

If I can forward any output (eg: HP-CHECK -t   which is clean, no warnings/errors) just ask !

Thanks for your attention and help,

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I've performed the following and my printer is working again, although I can't scan at present.

sudo apt-get autoremove xsane
sudo apt-get autoremove libsane-extras

I am will reinstall hplip-3.12.2.run  (HPLIP) and see if I can try this again !

thanks for all your support

Answer (score 1):

wondering if the original author got it working as I'm having the same problem.  Output from `hp-check -t --fix` says (among other things) xsane version is either missing or incompatible.  It was installed so I assumed the latter and removed it.  hp-check output didn't change.

After some run-around (and edits here) I went back to the hp-check output.  In it is a line referring to a permissions error.  I re-ran scanimage -L only t his time, traced it. i.e. `# strace -o strace-hp-check hp-check`.  Doing this as root and as a user demonstrated differences that got me to re-check group permissions.

The fix is adding the user account name to to `/etc/groups`, in the line for the lp group.  This is done either with an Ubuntu application specific for editing `/etc/group` (and `/etc/gshadow`) and adding the user account name to the line for the lp group.  (Using a comma as delimiter).

NOTE: The HP installation script may edit the file to add the user account to the lpadmin group.  This won't help.